# How to put div inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to put a div with a scrollbar inside foreach, Now the problem is, the output shows the div on each echoed data.

Comment: Give your code......

Comment: https://shrib.com/#foreachproblem

Comment: Can you provide result array so I can give you solution..?

Comment: I'm using $query->result();

Comment: I mean to say content of array..... use print_r($query->result()); and give me what you get by this

Comment: [concern] => hehehe [sent] => 2017-10-11 08:36:09 [flag] => 1 [adflag] => 1 [role] => student [stud_delete] => 0 [gui_delete] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [replyid] => 118 [blogid] => 16 [sender] => Alfred Santos Angeles [username] => 201410165 [reply] =>
oo

Comment: This array is not valid

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop will echo each time your loop iterates. I assume you are trying to echo the contents of some array or object into what are likely rows.

To do this, you would echo the open and close tags for the div outside of the foreach loop. You would then make the div a static height, and set the overflow to scroll. Using inline styles is not best practice, but I will use them in my example for the sake of brevity:

```
$listOfAnimalsOnNoahsArk = array('dog', 'cat','sheep','warewolf', '...');

echo '<div style="width:100%;height:500px;overflow:scroll">';
foreach($listOfAnimalsOnNoahsArk as $animal) {
    echo "<p>$animal</p>"; //Double quotes will print variable values
}
echo '</div>'; //Single quotes use less CPU because they print verbatim
```

Now, if you intended to replicate `<div>` in your `foreach` loop, your issue is simply a CSS one. Adjust the width and height to your needs.

[Edit]

Your code was posted after I made my comment. Here is how I would write the code to solve the problem you are working through:

```
<?php
if($results):
?>
  <div class="container"><!--You seem to only need one container-->
  <?php
  foreach($results as $blog): //Consider using the colon format (alternate syntax for control structures) for clarity
    if($blog->role == 'student'):
    ?>
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <a href="<?=base_url('main/delete/'.$blog->replyid)?>" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <?=$blog->reply.$blog->sent?>
      </div><!--Added this-->
    <?php
    //Note: "<?=" in php is the same as "<?php echo"
    endif;

    if($blog->role == 'guidance'):
    ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <a href="<?=base_url('main/delete/'.$blog->replyid)?>" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <?=$blog->sender.':'.$blog->reply.$blog->sent?>  
      </div><!--Added this-->
    <?php
    endif;
  endforeach;
  ?>
  </div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Your main issue is your main container needs to be outside of the loop. If I am wrong, writing in cleaner syntax will improve the readability of your code, and make moving elements around much easier. I opted for an alternate control structure `if():` and `endif;` to keep a clearer distinction between PHP logic and HTML output.

Comment: Yeah i'd like to try that but the consistency of my code is at stake, as you can see I used a lot of php opening and closing tags just to avoid that single quote method.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you answer based on your giving information.

It may works for you...

Please Ignore the array $results.

```
<?php 
$results[0] = json_decode(json_encode(array(
        'concern' => 'hehehe',
        'sent' => '2017-10-11 08:36:09',
        'flag' => 1,
        'adflag' => 1,
        'role' => 'student',
        'stud_delete' => 0,
        'gui_delete' => 0,
        'replyid' => 118,
        'blogid' => 16,
        'sender' => 'Alfred Santos Angeles',
        'username' => 201410165,
        'reply' => 'oo'
    )));

echo '<div class="container">'; 
if($results){ foreach ($results as $blog) { if($blog->role == 'student')echo '
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <a href="'.base_url('main/delete/'.$blog->replyid).'" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>'.$blog->reply.$blog->sent.'
        </div>';if($blog->role == 'guidance') echo '
        <div class="container">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                <a href="'.base_url('main/delete/'.$blog->replyid).'" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>'.$blog->sender.':'.$blog->reply.$blog->sent.'
            </div>
        </div>';}} echo '
    </div>';?>
```